# Internet Explorer 8 bug with display: table

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have the weirdest bug ever... I'm experimenting with display: table, and my proof of concept works on the very first try after opening a new process, but any subsequent reloading of the page breaks the design. Here is the simple HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: table;
        }

        .row {
            display: table-row;
        }

        .cell {
            display: table-cell;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            padding: 1em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">CELL A</div>
            <div class="cell">CELL B</div>
            <div class="cell">CELL C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the expected result, this is what I get after loading the first time.

[image]

Now that's what I get after reloading the page, with F5:

[image]

It's insane!!!

Can someone please try it and let me know how it comes out for them? Thank you. I hope I will not have killed myself by the time I read the solution :-)

Comment: @md1337: consider that IE8 has been out for a while. Why are you the first person to see this bug?

Comment: Works fine for me. (WindowsXP, 8.0.6001.18702)

Comment: I would highly discourage the display:(table/table-row/table-cell) CSS property. It is not well supported and is bound to have quirks. Honestly if what you are displaying is tabular data, *then use a table*. Tables are only evil when used for *layout*.

Comment: Check for compatibility mode. IE8 should render display: table.  Maybe you should simply use a table?

Comment: Oh, and could not reproduce (http://xkcd.com/583/)

Comment: @md1337 It doesn't matter if it is what you are asking. You are using error-prone CSS and complaining that you are getting an error. Just don't use error-prone CSS in the first place.

Comment: @md1337, I get the same thing in design view even after using "<meta http-equiv...." - Would you please let me know how did you solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It turns out that, as suggested by some, IE's compatibility mode was triggered somehow.

I found out that it's because I'm running the page on an Intranet, and by default compatibility mode is enabled for Intranet websites.

This can be disabled by going to Tools > Compatibility View Settings and unchecking the Display intranet sites in Compatibility View box. Of course this is not something you necessarily want to ask all your users to do, so it was suggested to me to add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

in the header, which works great.

More info on that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 6):

The problem when the browser is in compatibility view. (as suggested by taylorjes)

When the page is displayed in normal view, the cells are horizontal. When displayed in compatibility view, the cells are vertical.

As I said in my comment, I would highly discourage the display:(table/table-row/table-cell) CSS property. It is not well supported and is bound to have quirks.

Honestly if what you are displaying is tabular data, *then use a table*. Tables are only evil when used for *layout*.

Comment: @md1337 - You don't. You write your code to be compatible across multiple browsers (thus my remarks discouraging the use of those CSS properties).

Comment: @md1337. Oh, and before you think otherwise, the down vote was not from me. It is a legitimate question, even if the answer is not what you wanted ;)

Comment: `alert(document.documentMode)` will tell you `8` or `7` (or `5` for quirks mode). Use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>` to force IE to use the ‘best’ Standards Mode it has available. Otherwise you may fall victim to Compatibility Mode if requested, defaulted or accidentally-clicked by the user, or if Microsoft puts you on the Compatibility list.

Comment: @bobince: Great comment! You saved the day.