# CSS Div not going 100% height for my content

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS Code:

```
html, body {
    font-family:Arial;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:#0CF;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#page-body {
    width:75%;
    min-height:600px;
    height:100%;
    border-top:5px solid #c6d6e9;
    background:#c6d6e9;
    margin:10px auto 30px auto;
    padding:10px;
}
#page-body-inner {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

.page-left {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:190px;
}
.page-right {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:700px;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

for some reason, the height of the content on the right is not 100% so the text goes off the div with a background colour.

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yKCJG/

Comment: try `display:inline-block` you cannot set dimensions for `inline` objects, also you may want to use min-height 100% on your html and body as if your content is longer than your viewport it will get cut off

Comment: don't not use height:100% use height:auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `#page-body` add `display:table;`

http://jsfiddle.net/yKCJG/2/

```
#page-body {
    width:75%;
    min-height:600px;
    height:100%;
    border-top:5px solid #c6d6e9;
    background:#c6d6e9;
    margin:10px auto 30px auto;
    padding:10px;
    display:table;

}
```

Comment: Note that Internet Explorer only supports `display: table` since version 8. The other major browsers have had good support for a time. http://caniuse.com/css-table

Comment: @michaelward82 please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764699/internet-explorer-8-bug-with-display-table

Answer (score 0):

Try this just remove the `height:100%` and put `height:auto`

```
#page-body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 hsl(213, 44%, 85%);
    border-top: 5px solid hsl(213, 44%, 85%);
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px auto 30px;
    min-height: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 75%;
}
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Don't restrict the height of elements to 100%. You can apply that for min-height. The problem is when you float elements they lose their scope to parents. So, you got to apply a clearfix to the parent element whose childs are floated.

The best one is [NicolasGallagher's clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

Easy to use. Import this and add class name as 'cf' to the parent element ('page-body' in your case). That's it, now the child element increases the dimension of parent element even if it's floated.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the inner divs are floated so the parent div #pagebody has no actual height.
There are 2 ways to solve this.

1. Remove the height:100% on the #pagebody and add `overflow:hidden`.
2. Remove the height:100% on the #pagebody and add:

   ```
   #page-body:after{
      content: '.';
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      visibility: hidden;
      font-size: 0;
      line-height: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      clear:both
      }
   ```